# How do I play two bass clefs sharing piano keys?

Tags: piano, notation, clefs

I have some sheet music for the song Mad World. Part way though the treble clef on the grand staff changes to bass, which is fine, but a few bars later I hit a snag.

In bar 7 both hands are given the same notes, the very same keys. There's no indication of having shifted octave, as far as I can see; it just has the left hand playing semibreve (whole notes) high E and G while the right plays them as successive crotchets (quarters)

Should I play the left hand an octave lower, or is this just not playable on a single piano? Or is there something else that I've missed?

Note: I can never quite get a grip on American rhythmic terminology, please forgive any mistake.

[image: Sheetmusic from https://musescore.com/user/6185336/scores/2288536]

Comment: Also, is there an ottava **line** that you may have overlooked in Bar 7?

Comment: I had to look up an example of that but, no, there is none.

Comment: I did a google image search for the sheet music and after seeing eventually found [a version that may be similar to yours](https://musescore.com/user/6185336/scores/2288536).  I will edit the question to add that version with the section in question highlighted.

Comment: Btw, if can get hold of an image, you can simply copy/paste it into your question and Stack Exchange will take care of image hosting. If you open this question on a phone, for instance, you might be able to simply snap a picture, copy it to the clipboard, and paste into the body of the question. It sounds very much like it's simply representing two voices that are simply overlapping (perhaps as a result of transcribing from multiple instruments)...

Comment: I suppose it does, thank you. I'm still a little confused but trying to learn.